# Option dialog in Jface

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I'm used to work with Swing and usually I use `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...)` for showing to the user a set of options to be chossed.

Now I'm switching to Jface for an Eclipse plugin...Is there an alternative to `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a good solution was using the ListDialog class as explained [here](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/discover-eclipses-jface-dialog?page=0,2).